# Howto get Autocomplete for the Propertys in Eclipse

Tags: android

Is it possible to get Autocomplete or Something when i work with the eclipse form editor?
I write a color in the strings.xml and then i want to select it by the propertys for the text color, but there is no autocomplete or something equal

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, you **want** autocomplete / intellisence for a content in an XML file? Correct?

As far I know that is not possible, as Eclipse does not parse those files. However being Eclipse there is more than likely a plugin available to do *exactly* what you want.

Quickly googling around I found this post on the Eclipse forums that you want to try: [XML autocomplete?](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools/msg29697.html).

HTH,

Comment: I mean somethink like in this screenshot (Reference Chooser)
http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/images/first46.gif

Comment: @mobbek_hobbed: Sorry, I haven't used Eclipse enough to know how to do that. I am sure what you want is *possible* using a plugin, search or post on the eclipse forums.